# React-redux: Is it okay to connect all existing action-creators to each redux-connected component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I see why I shouldn't connect the entire redux state to each component. But what about action-creators? Can I just have an index file, that exports all action-creators in one default export and connect all at once to each component without picking them one by one?

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { RootState } from '../../redux/rootReducer'
import allActions from '../../redux/actions'

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {
  const { someState } = state
  return {
    someState
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, allActions)(WhateverScreen)
```

Answer (score -1):

1. connecting the entire redux state to your component may leave you with performance issue since react components update on state/prop updates so your component may be left with several unnecessary rerenders.
2. I wouldn't want to import all my actions that would just possibly bloat bundle size which we always try to keep as small as possible. Imagine if you have 100 defined actions imported on every file that dispatches.

i would rather:

```js
import {action1, action2} from '/path/to/all/actions'
```

Comment: are you suggesting that compiler duplicates entries each time they imported? Or that you have hundreds of huge action files defined but never imported anywhere??

Comment: `import allActions from '../../redux/actions'` loads up all the actions in a single file right, when you are just using a few of those actions in a single file